# Read the value of a local variable in Windchill

Tags: ptc-windchill

I created a local attribute on Part. The attribute is of Boolean type and is a synchronized attribute.

In my code, I'm trying to get the value of that attribute. Following the code:

```
PersistableAdapter  pa = new PersistableAdapter (product,null,null,null);
pa.load("isImageChanged");
System.out.println("Value is:: "+ pa.get("isImageChanged"));
```

The value is in sys out is always coming as null. Am I missing anything here?

Windchill/FlexPLM V11

Comment: Are you sure `product` here is variable for WTPart object?

Answer (score 0):

Your Logic is good, are you sure the internal name of attribute **isImageChanged** & object you have used in PersistableAdapter is correct? 
also you can try storing the value in Object and then typecast it to Boolean.

Sample

```
PersistableAdapter obj = new PersistableAdapter(my_persistable,null,null,null);
obj.load(“name”);
Object nameValue = obj.get(“name”);
```

Comment: I think I missed to sync from db after adding the db columns. 

AddColumns -syncFromDB

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.